# Used latest state in Fetch API `then()`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a REACT hook component that fetches data using the Fetch API `fetch`. Though, I'm facing an issue that I'm not quite sure how to solve it, or better said, I'm not sure if is there any "recommended" way to face this issue.

Take this code in example:

```
const Fetcher = () => {
    [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
        fetch('http://www.myapi.com')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                const newData = [...data];
                newData.push(json);

                setData(newData);
            });
    }

    return <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Click to fetch</button>
}
```

It's not a working example, but it's pretty clear what is happening: I click a button and I fetch something; that something is ADDED to the current state.

Now, where is the problem? When I wrote `const newData = [...data]` I'm considering the `data` variable that was available in the moment the `fetch` started, NOT the current `data`. This means that, if the `fetch` takes 1 minute to be executed, in that minute the `data` could have been updated some other way, so, when the `fetch.then().then()` is called, I override the actual current `data` with something that is not correct.

I can give you this scheme to make you understand better:

1. I click and a first `fetch` is executed with `data` equals to `[ ]`;
2. I click again before the first `fetch` ends (again, with `data` equals to `[ ]`;
3. Second fetch ends and in `data` is saved the new value (e.g. `['foo']`);
4. First fetch ends receiving 'bar'. Since it use its `data` that is an empty array, it save in `data` the array `['bar']`;

As you can see, at the end of the day, I have an array `['bar']`, when instead it should be `['foo', 'bar']`.

To this issue, I've come up with two solutions:

1. Keeping a copy of the state in a `ref`, and use that in the `fetch.then().then()`. Something like this:

   ```
   const Fetcher = () => {
       [data, setData] = useState([]);
       const refData = useRef(data);

       const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
           fetch('http://www.myapi.com')
               .then(response => response.json())
               .then(json => {
                   const newData = [...refData.current];
                   newData.push(json);

                   setData(newData);
               });
       }

       useEffect(() => {
           refData.current = data;
       }, [data]);

       return <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Click to fetch</button>
   }
   ```
2. Use a temporary variable and an useEffect to work on the latest variable:

   ```
   const Fetcher = () => {
       [data, setData] = useState([]);
       [lastFetchedData, setLastFetchedData] = useState();

       const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
           fetch('http://www.myapi.com')
               .then(response => response.json())
               .then(json => {
                   setLastFetchedData(json);
               });
       }

       useEffect(() => {
           const newData = [...data];
           newData.push(lastFetchedData);

           setData(newData);
       }, [lastFetchedData]);

       return <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Click to fetch</button>
   }
   ```

I'm pretty sure that both of them work without creating any major issue, but:

1. **First approach**: I don't know, it seems to me it goes against REACT way of thinking. I'm using a ref to maintain the state up-to-date somewhere.. I mean, I don't know if this is OK for REACT "way-of-living";
2. **Second approach**: In this case I use only states. What I don't like here is that I do an extra render ANY time some data is fetched. Not big deal, but, you know, if it could be avoided it would be better. I could return an empty page if `lastFetchedData` is not `null`, but the user would see that empty page for maybe a millisecond. Actually, it wouldn't see the empty page, but probably the page blink due to the two renders;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual solution is to use the callback form of `setData`:

```
const Fetcher = () => {
    [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
        fetch('http://www.myapi.com')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                setData(data => [...data, json]); // <============
            });
    }

    return <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Click to fetch</button>
}
```

---

Side notes:

1. Your code is falling prey to the footgun in the `fetch` API I describe [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html). You need to check `response.ok` before calling `json`.
2. You aren't handling errors from `fetch`.
3. You've forgotten to declare `data` and `setData` (I recommend using strict mode so this is an error):

So:

```
const Fetcher = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
//  ^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− #3

    const handleButtonClick = (e) => {
        fetch('http://www.myapi.com')
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {                                   // #1
                    throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status); // #1
                }                                                     // #1
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(json => {
                setData(data => [...data, json]);
            })
            .catch(error => {                                         // #2
                // Handle/report error here                           // #2
            });                                                       // #2
    }

    return <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Click to fetch</button>
}
```

Comment: Ok, I feel dumb as hell because it's so easy and I didn't think about the easiest thing :/ Just one question: since the `setData` used there is the one defined when `fetch` was first run, could be possible that the `data` used inside the callback is still the old one?

Comment: @Jolly - No, the setter functions you get from `useState` have two useful aspects: 1. They're stable (you always get the same copy of `setData`, it's not recreated every time), and 2. When you use the callback form, they always use the up-to-date version of the data. And don't feel dumb! A **lot** of people wouldn't have realized the problem with `data` being stale! :-)

Comment: Well, thank you. i've made a quick a test and.. it easy as you said, very thank you. For the `const` before the useState, yes sorry, I was writing the code directly here so I missed that. Instead, for the `fetch` `response.ok` I know: usually I wrote an "enhancer" for the `fetch` with some chain methods available. The fact that the `catch` only catches the network error it's pretty missleading at first. Thank you for the time though!